# python showing 'ModuleNotFoundError' despite module folder being located in the active environment

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, package

As part my project, I need [the OpenCV package](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html) for Python. Following its instructions, I install and extract the appropriate "
`cv2.pyd` package to the `.venv\Lib\site-packages\` folder. When I attempt to import the module from the terminal, however, it gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError`, and similarly `pip show cv2` gives:

> WARNING: Package(s) not found: cv2

I tried entering:

```
pip show pandas
```

into the terminal to go to the `site-packages` folder to confirm that the `cv2.pyd` file does exist there.

**Update:** I reinstalled python and it's associated packages from the anaconda program, which seems to resolve this issue. I'm still uncertain as to the cause of the original errors.

Comment: is numpy and matplotlib packages in site-packages folder and do those work?

Comment: Running "import numpy", "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt", and various other methods from those libraries have resolved the issue.